# How to modernize my PGP?

Tags: gnupg

I am on ubuntu 16.04 and I need to use GPG/TAILS PGP4USB  GNUPG since my system is a bit old.

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

1. What's the easiest/fastest way for me to solve this? Will upgrade my ubuntu solve it? I am afraid to upgrade since it can take some time to setup my laptop (I use I3 and have a bunch of configs for the hardware).
2. What about alternatives such as Kleopatra or Tails?

Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is a software stack from 2016-April (time of release). A search on packages.ubuntu.com will show versions of a package that are used by various release (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnupg&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).  Don't forget 16.04 LTS hasn't much of its 5 year *standard* support life left.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.04, `gnupg` package is in `main` repository, so it is still updated for security issues and safe to use.

For new features, you can install [`gnupg2`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnupg2) in 16.04:

```
$ sudo apt install gnupg2
$ gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11
libgcrypt 1.6.5
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Comment: when i try to install it i see: `gnupg2 is already the newest version (2.1.11-6ubuntu2.1)`

1. how do I use it?
2. does it mean that the requirement for 'GPG/TAILS PGP4USB GNUPG' is met?

Thanks!

Comment: the command will be `gpg2` instead of `gpg`